Prove inequality $f(x_{k+1})\leq f(x_k)-\frac{1}{2L}\|\nabla f(x_k)\|^2$
This question seems unique.
I did some past papers (no solutions) from my optimization course, and I am stuck on the following problem:
Given $f$ is a continuously differentiable on $\mathbb{R}^n$ with a global minimum $x^*$, and   real numbers $0<\gamma<L$, such that $f(y)\geq f(x)+\nabla f(x)^T(y-x)+\frac{\gamma}{2}\|y-x\|^2$ and $f(y)\leq f(x)+\nabla f(x)^T(y-x)+\frac{L}{2}\|y-x\|^2$.
Moreover, given some more properties:

$x_{k+1}=x_k-\alpha_k\nabla f(x_k)$
Let $z\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and positive $c$, then $\min_{y\in\mathbb{R}^n}\{\nabla f(z)^T(y-z)+\frac{c}{2}\|y-z\|^2\}=-\frac{1}{2c}\|\nabla f(z)\|^2$

Prove the following: $$f(x_{k+1})\leq f(x_k)-\frac{1}{2L}\|\nabla f(x_k)\|^2$$
My solution:
$$\begin{aligned}
f(x_{k+1})&\leq f(x_k)+\nabla f(x_k)^T(x_{k+1}-x_k)+\frac{L}{2}\|x_{k+1}-x_k\|^2\\
&=f(x_k)+\nabla f(x_k)^T(-\alpha_k\nabla f(x_k))+\frac{L}{2}\|-\alpha_k\nabla f(x_k)\|^2\\
&=f(x_k)+(\frac{L\alpha_k^2}{2}-\alpha_k)\|\nabla f(x_k)\|^2
\end{aligned}$$
However, I am stuck, how can I furthur simplify $\frac{L\alpha_k^2}{2}-\alpha_k$. I can only do so if $\alpha_k=\frac{1}{L}$. Thanks!

I think the result should hold for $\alpha_k\in [0,2/L]$ or $\alpha_k\in [0,1/L]$, not necessarily one specific point.

Note: I suspect the prompt here is incomplete and the reader was intended to assume $\alpha_k = 1/L$ for all $k$.
The desired inequality holds when $\alpha_k = 1/L$, as you noted.
More generally, if $\alpha_k \leq 1/L$, then
$$ - \left( 1 - \frac{\alpha_k L}{2}\right) 
=  \frac{\alpha_k L}{2} - 1\ 
\leq  \frac{1}{2} - 1 
= - \frac{1}{2}.
$$
Thus, if $\alpha_k \leq 1/L$, then the inequality derived in the question implies
$$f(x_{k+1}) \leq f(x_k) - \frac{\alpha_k}{2}\|\nabla f(x_k)\|^2.$$
For reference, check out Ryan Tibshirani's notes
